# How balanced is the Nathair's Mischief spell from UA: Draconic Options?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, unearthed-arcana

*Nathair's Mischief* is a spell from the relatively new [UA 2021: Draconic Options](https://media.wizards.com/2021/downloads/Unearthed-Arcana-2021-Draconic-Options.pdf), p. 6.

How balanced is it in its current iteration when compared to similar options published in non-playtest material? Does it introduce any problematic ruling situations that you have experienced during your playtest?

Comment: I may be able to tell you in a few weeks, since that is one of the spells I will take at my next bard level up; we are play testing a few of those UA features in a campaign I am in but the campaign is 'play' not a 'play test as our purpose' campaign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129539/discussion-between-akixkisu-and-thomas-markov).

Answer (score 2):

#### It looks to be about as strong as Web.

I think the best comparison to this spell is *Web*. They are both 2nd-level Wizard spells, they both cover the same area (a 20-foot cube), and they both inflict status effects on a failed save that can significantly impair an enemy's ability to fight. The main differences between them are that the area of *Nathair's Mischief* can move, while *Web*'s is stationary, and that *Web*'s effects can last for multiple rounds on a failed save, while *Nathair's Mischief*'s effects only last for a single round.

Overall, I'd say that they're both fairly strong crowd control spells, but neither is strictly better than the other.